# BDD/TDD with CodeIgniter

Tags: php, unit-testing, tdd, bdd, codeigniter-2

I recently joined a company that uses codeigniter. I have been using nodejs and rails a ton so I feel like I am missing BDD like tools (rspec/jasmine/mocha). Does PHP and/or CodeIgniter have any sort of CLI based testing suite. If so, how should I structure my app? Any good conventions that can be followed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a project called CIUnit that integrates [phpunit](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.6/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html) to codeigniter and provides some helpful functions, and make it a generally pleasant experience. Unfortunately the [official branch](http://www.knollet.com/foostack/) is stopped at CI version 1.7.2, but [there's a fork](https://bitbucket.org/kenjis/my-ciunit/) that I've been using for 2.1.2.

This gives you the usual xUnit style test suites, code coverage report generators, selenium integration, mock and stub objects and such.

Comment: Worked for me with some modifications! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Two most popular PHP BDD frameworks should work just fine with any PHP project:

- [Behat](http://behat.org/) (StoryBDD)
- [PHPSpec](https://github.com/phpspec/phpspec) (SpecBDD)

Comment: Ahhh awesome!! I'll take a look at them.

Answer (score 0):

Today's best solution would be PHPUnit and Selenium. I wrote articles covering the usage here:

- On PHPUnit: http://taiar.github.io/php/2013/11/08/testing-codeigniter-applications-with-phpunit/
- On PHPUnit with Selenium: http://taiar.github.io/php/2014/04/21/acceptance-tests-on-codeigniter-with-phpunit-and-selenium/